# Is there a way to reverse a tuple's order in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a shorthand way to reverse a tuples order in Julia? E.g. given:

`x = (1,2)::Tuple`

```
reverseTuple(x)
(2,1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`reverse(x)` should do what you expect.